# Found these bugs on a sticker in an old shoe box. What are they?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image][image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
What are these bugs? I found them in an old shoe box on a sticker that was sitting on the carpet.

Comment: Hi, those pictures are really blurry. It would be helpful if you tried to take better photos, also with a scale to have a better understanding of their size.

Comment: I updated the photos, hopefully that is easier to see. Thank you!